# CSS gradient has stripes (not smooth)

Tags: html, css, cordova

I have a `div` that has a background image. But the image is too bright, and so that form elements would look good on it (white elements on bottom of the page and top) I have added a gradient overlay, that should `darken` about 20% from bottom and top and be transparent on the center.

So here is my code:

```css
.landing-carousel .carousel-item::before {
    background: rgb(111,111,111); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6f6f6f', endColorstr='#6f6f6f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And here is the result from Samsung Galaxy A9 (same is also on Windows). But on Samsung Galaxy S6/S7/S10 all is okay.

Notice the stripes? Why the gradient isn't smooth?

[image: Gradient]

Comment: I think this comes down to the different rendering engines in different browsers. There's some methods to reduce banding but I'm not aware of anything that is guaranteed to work in all browsers all the time. That said, try this and see if it fixes your issue https://twitter.com/stevenfabre/status/674026963644760070

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the prefix lines first. Some browsers might use the wrong implementation if they support both. You could try this.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
background: rgb(111,111,111); /* Old browsers */  //Put this at the end, but i'd just delete this line.
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6f6f6f', endColorstr='#6f6f6f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

[Css troubleshooting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS)

But [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) states that now you can remove most prefixes, as Chrome and Firefox support it just fine. So try to remove them as well and perhaps just try this

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(111,111,111,0.1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
background: rgb(111,111,111); /* Old browsers */ //Put this at the end, but i'd just delete this line.
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6f6f6f', endColorstr='#6f6f6f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Nop it doesn't help